# Duplicating display on single monitor

Tags: display

I have a pc with Windows XP Embedded that is duplicating the image displayed on the monitor screen. It's scrunching it up and displaying it 2.5 times on the one monitor. I checked connections to the monitor screen and I looked in the display settings, but I couldn't find anything. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried connecting a different monitor to the PC or a different PC to the monitor in order to find out which is having the issue?

Comment: @CharlieRB See my comment to Jason below.

Comment: "I looked in the display settings, but I couldn't find anything" - That doesn't help us know what you've tried already. :/  Have you ensured the resolution and refresh rate is set right (in the display/monitor settings in Windows)?

Comment: @techie007  Sorry, yeah that was a little vague, but yes I checked all the display settings and nothing was out of the ordinary.  Everything appeared to be as it should.

Comment: If you turn the resolution down, does it affect it any?  Does it look the same in Safe Mode?  How about in the BIOS?  How about a 3rd party OS (IE a LiveCD)?  If it still looks messed up in the BIOS or in another OS, then it's hardware, and you need to start swapping parts to figure out what's at fault.

Comment: Resolution is fixed at 640x480 so I can't change that.  It does duplicate throughout the entire boot process (ie, the BIOS/POST screens) which, as you say, seems to suggest hardware failure.  Thanks for the help, I do appreciate it.  I'm not a techie, I'm a programmer, but since I'm one of only two IT people, a lot of this kind of stuff ends up in my lap.

Comment: No problem, but may I suggest that if you're going to do the job of a tech, you should probably learn to troubleshoot like one. ;) That's not meant to be a slag or anything, just advice. :)

Comment: No worries, I didn't take it as an insult.  I know I have things to work on... :)  I'm learning.  Slowly, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen on a broken monitor.  I suggest testing it with a different monitor.

Comment: This is on a very compact system and the monitor connection is of a very compact design as well and quite likely proprietary (although it might be the same as what's in a laptop, not sure).  Long story short, we don't have another monitor we can just plug into it and test without buying one from the company that sold it to us.  Have any other suggestions to try first?

Comment: Since it was indicated in the comments that the problem exists outside of Windows, it _is_ a hardware problem of some kind.